# 502 (Bad Gateway) - Nginx + Mono (OpenBSD 5.3)

Tags: nginx, mono, openbsd, xsp

I am having trouble getting Mono to work with nginx.  I installed OpenBSD 5.3 and set up the appropriate (package) ports.  I built mono, mono-xsp and nginx - all without incident.  All three appear to be working OK, but not in conjunction.

I am trying to run the default VS MVC3 template web app, but keep getting a 502 (Bad gateway).  In the error logs, I see the following:

```
[crit] 31764#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,*
```

The frustrating thing is that /tmp/fastcgi.socket does exist.  I tried 'touch' and making sure 'wheel' and 'www' has the appropriate permissions (chmod 775 and 777).  The result of 'ls -la /tmp/fastcgi.socket' revealed nothing awry.

Here is my config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        access_log   /home/www/nginx.log;
        error_log    /home/www/errors.log;

        # root /home/www/test;
        # index index.html index.htm index.aspx default.aspx;

        location ^~ /Scripts/ { }
        location ^~ /Content/ { }

        location / {
            root /home/www/test;
            # fastcgi_index /;

            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket;

            # include        fastcgi_params;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna hazard a guess that OpenBSD ports runs nginx jailed or chrooted. So check that first and if so you'll need to change the socket path to be created inside the jailed root.

Comment: Thanks Melvyn - You were spot on. I am able to serve a simple aspx file now (OpenBSD's nginx port chroot(8)s to /var/www/<blah>, so the socket should live in there somewhere). Next stop - MVC :-)